# Magento homepage site title for 11 different websites

Tags: magento, multilingual

I have a multi-store Magento installation for 11 different domains all selling the same product but targeting different countries, currencies and languages.

I have one CMS homepage at the moment set with content being pulled in with static blocks and a featured category. The title for all 11 websites is 'Home Page' in english.

I want to be able to change the meta title of each site, is there a way I can do this without having to create 11 separate CMS homepages in the admin and then assigning each website to it's specific CMS page? It seems overkill to have to create a separate page to change just change one line on each website.

Answer (score 0):

The title, meta-keywords and meta-description are added to the page from here: `Mage_Cms_Block_Page::_prepareLayout()`, to be more exact, on these lines:

```
if ($head) {
    $head->setTitle($page->getTitle());
    $head->setKeywords($page->getMetaKeywords());
    $head->setDescription($page->getMetaDescription());
}
```

I see here 2 quick options:

1. You override the method mentioned above and replace `$head->setTitle($page->getTitle())` with `$head->setTitle($this->__($page->getTitle()))` and add to your translation files the translation of `Home page` for every language.
2. You override the method `Mage_Cms_Model_Page::getTitle()` and make it return a translated version of the title then again add `Home page` to your translation files.

I recommend the first option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 11 sites all selling the same item, duplicate content could very well become an issue, especially if you are dealing with hundreds+ skus. I would suggest doing the individual CMS pages like you first suggested and change more than just the META data.

Also, in System>Configuration>Design, you can change the Title Prefix and Suffix and default info per site so that may help as well.